# Best books mostly written formally in symbolic logic

Tags: reference-request, book-recommendation

To me, symbollic mathematics is much more clear then messy meta-language. But most textbooks I find are written in normal English.

Do you know any good books (preferably a series) which are mostly written symbolically.

I hope this question is not too broad. I was just curious and interested. Maybe you will change my following year(s) ;)